# Arraylist in a separate java file neither an activity or fragment, how to get the string value from string.xml?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, string.xml

Good day, I would like to know or ask for help. I'm having a hard time getting the string value from my app's string.xml. I am accessing it through an Arraylist (in a separate java file. arraylist is not inside the activity or fragment).

I tried both String.valueOf and Integer.toString (refer below ss):

[image]

but the results for the both are the same(please refer below ss):

[image]

the left items are supposed to be a string value from my string.xml but I don't know how and why. I also tried Resources.getString but it crashes the app.

Do you have any idea that I can try in solving this problem? Thank you, it will be very much appreciated and sorry for the time answering my question.

EDIT: Here's the code(please see ss below) and I also tried the getString() suggestion.
[image]

sorry I'm really not good in development but I'm willing to listen and learn.

Comment: What is this class, and is it static? Show some code, not images.

Comment: @TheWanderer hello please see above (I added some). thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `context` argument to your function:

```
public static ArrayList<CategoryObject> getCategories(Context context) {
    final ArrayList<CategoryObject> categoryObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    final Resources resources = context.getResources();

    CategoryObject categoryObject = new CategoryObject();
    categoryObject.setCategoryTitle(resources.getString(R.string.psi));
    categoryObject.setItem1(resources.getString(R.string.psi1));
    categoryObject.setItem2(resources.getString(R.string.psi2));
    categoryObject.setItem3(resources.getString(R.string.psi3));
    categoryObject.setItem4(resources.getString(R.string.psi4));

    categoryObjects.add(categoryObject);

    return categoryObjects;
}
```

<sub>Notice that I changed your ArrayList variable name to use Java's camelCase standard (`CategoryObjects` --> `categoryObjects).</sub>

Then you just need to pass a Context object to it.

From an Activity:

```
Category.getCategories(this);
```

From a Fragment:

```
Category.getCategories(getActivity());
```

In the future, please *paste* your code as *text*. It's actually a lot easier than taking a screenshot.

Comment: Wow! thank you for sharing it. indeed it worked! And thank you for giving me another important notes in development's standard and for the suggestions. I will take note of these and thank you thank you very much TheWanderer for the help!